# Using fancyBox on Bigcommerce

Tags: jquery, fancybox, bigcommerce

Been trying to use fancyBox on a bigcommerce store site and I cannot get it to work for youtube media.  All the files are on the server and they are linked correctly.

When I click on the sample link the youtube comes up full screen instead of the lightbox frame.

Anyone else have this issue?

http://www.gopowersports.com/old-how-to-videos/

Comment: Showing us your code would be helpful.

Comment: Never mind got it to work.

Comment: Showing us the answer would be helpful.

Comment: The css file had not transferred over correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be that your CSS is not loading properly, and so your style rules are not applying to the YouTube video/embed.  If you provide code, I'd be happy to help you show you what CSS is applying and what CSS your site needs, and to generally sort out this issue.

Let me know if this helps and if you have nay other questions.